# Button to hide HTML Tampermonkey

Tags: html, hide, tampermonkey

Hello im trying to get a code working for tampermonkey, Where if you click a button it will hide a piece of HTML and when you click it again it shows up again.

```
    let newImg4 = document.createElement("img");
newImg4.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/63/63801.png";
newImg4.style = `position: absolute; bottom: 290px; right: 20px; z-index: 100000; width: 50px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer;`;
document.body.prepend(newImg4);
newImg4.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let w = HIDE HTML HERE!("<iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=yesihavetheidijuswanttokeepittomyselffornow&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use toggle class 
   `newImg4.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (this.style.display === "none") {
    this.style.display = "block";
  } else {
   this.style.display = "none";
  }
});`

Comment: It does not appear to be working, Could you show it in a full script format so incuding other lines i maybe dont have yet? Since this does not seem to be working for me :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to first get the iframe (the comment from Hisham missed that), and then set its display style to none.

```js
let newImg4 = document.createElement("img");
newImg4.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/63/63801.png";
newImg4.style = `position: absolute; bottom: 290px; right: 20px; z-index: 100000; width: 50px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer;`;
document.body.prepend(newImg4);
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
newImg4.addEventListener("click", () => { if (elem.style.display === "none") { elem.style.display = "block"; } else { elem.style.display = "none"; } });
```

```html
<iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=yesihavetheidijuswanttokeepittomyselffornow&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```